# SQL: Get different row values from different column values sql

Tags: sql

I'm trying to calculate running averages of past 4th month. So I need to get the 4th value of each month

```
month_date | col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3| Col_4
---------------------------------------------
 11   |   0    |   0     |   0    |   0
 10   |   2    |   0     |   0    |   0
 09   |   3    |   4     |   0    |   0
 08   |   8    |   7     |   9    |   0
 07   |   6    |   8     |   11   |   5
 06   |   3    |   4     |   0    |   8
 05   |   8    |   7     |   9    |   9
 04   |   6    |   8     |   11   |   5
```

[Expected Output]

```
 | Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3| Col_4
----------------------------------------
  |   6     |   4     |   9    |   5
```

What I tried to do

- I tried to rank excluding zeros
  like row_number over (order by month desc) - that didn't work

-I tried to to use NULLS LAST function that didn't work either because I need to order based on month not on each month

Please help

Comment: I removed the inconsistent tags.  Please explain the logic for the calculation.  It is not obvious.  You have months going across and months as a column, so the question is not at all clear.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot makes things easier:

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8e9c0091e41fef974f3e89cea4ac17ef)</sup>**

```
select *
  from (
    select c, val
      from t unpivot (val for c in (col1 as 1, col2 as 2, col3 as 3, col4 as 4))
      where month_date + c = 4 + (select min(month_date) from t) ) 
  pivot (max(val) for c in (1 m1, 2 m2, 3 m3, 4 m4))
```

Comment: Thank you . This helped.